# Texments package not working on Ubuntu

Tags: latex, pygments

I am trying to use the Texments Latex package on Ubuntu to do syntax highlighting.
Texments is a wrapper around Pygments.
I installed Texments and followed the steps to add the style file to the path.
But when I try to compile the .tex file, I get the error.

!Undefined Control Sequence

and then it prints out a bunch of wierd characters and places the ? prompt.
Anybody facing this error? What is the resolution?

If there is any other better way to provide syntax highlighting of source code I would be glad to accept it.

I know there is something called "listings" but frankly, i did not find the colors so good in it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could give [`minted`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/) a try … it basically does the same as `texments` but has more features and is a little more robust in the face of errors.

<sub>Furthermore, as the maintainer of `minted` I’m always glad of error reports. ;-)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Texments uses a special control sequence for pdftex to allow shell escapes, needed to call the `pygmentize` binary.  You need to call it with `pdflatex`, and you need to pass `pdflatex` the `-shell-escape` switch.  Cf. [the texments documentation](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/texments/texments.pdf).

Comment: You are referring to pdftex or pdflatex command? I did "pdflatex -shell-escape ants.clj"  Is this wrong? This is what I understood from the doc.

Comment: pdflatex: I've edited my answer. pdflatex should be run on the .tex file: if you have external code, you should use the \includecode{filename.ext} to refer to the code. pdflatex will then run pygmentize -on this file, creating a temporary latex file that it will then \input. You shouldn't be running pdflatex on any *.clj files.

Comment: Oh .. That was my typo ... I did pdflatex -shell-escape on the .tex file only. And that gave me that error.

Comment: Looks like you've got a debugging task.  I'd start with looking at the *.out.pyg file that the pygmentize creates (or should do!) when invoked by pdflatex.  For a wild guess, weird characters sounds like the -f latex option might be being ignored for some reason, so that you are getting junk passed into pdftex's gentle digestive system...  Good luck!